# How to tell if a numerical solution of a differential equation is accurate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Say I want to solve $(\nabla^2+k^2)F=0$ for some boundary conditions, and I have obtained numerical values on a grid. I can find the numerical laplacian but it is obviously not going to add up to $0$ exactly with $k^2$ times itself.

How can I tell how accurate the numerical solution is? It makes no sense to me to say $(\nabla^2+k^2)F$ must be 'small' because $k^2$ could be a small number itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to estimate the error when you do not know the error is to solve the equation with stepsizes $h$ and then with stepsizes $h/2$. If you are using an order 1 method, this should approximately halve the error, and you can estimate the error as the difference between these two solutions. So if the total error between these two solutions is $5.13\times 10^{-3}$, then your error estimate is something like $10^{-2}$.

If you have an order 2 method, halving the stepsize should quarter the error. So you can do a similar back-of-the-envelope calculation.

Some little tidbits. This approximation becomes more accurate as $h$ gets smaller (indeed, order of accuracy is defined in the limit as $h$ goes to zero), so you want $h$ small enough. Instead of halving you can make this more accurate by quartering or more, and adjust the math accordingly. Lastly, since we're talking about PDEs, you have to change $h$ around and $\Delta x$, knowing the order for both to get a rough estimate. Also in this case to even calculate the error you have to choose a norm like $l^2$ or maximum norm. Choose a norm the method is stable in.